# php MYSQL overwrite last connection link

Tags: php, mysql, database

### Background

I have a project which has been developed about several years. A lot of code is outdated and uses old programming style. Now I changed the database structure. I moved some tables to a new database which are still on the same server.

There are a lot of `mysql_*` functions remaining without the database resource given (`$link` is not set). In important cases I already replaced the database access to a newer programming style but because of the mass of code I cannot simply replace all `mysql_*` functions.

### Question

The problem is that all `mysql_*` functions without the resource given will connect to the last opened database. In my case the last opened database is the wrong database. I want to change this "default"-connection.

**Some code for better understanding**

```
// old database, new connection is forced
$db1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 
// new database, new connection is forced
$db2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);
mysql_select_db($dbn2, $db2);
```

Both database connections have the same `$hostname`, the same `$username` and the same `$password`. They only differ in the database (`$dbn1` and `$dbn2`).

```
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db1); // $dbn1
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db2); // $dbn2
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();"); // $dbn2 <- this should be changed
```

The database (without the given resource) will now have the last connection which is the `$db2`. But for backwards compatibility I want it to be `$db1`.

### Already tried solutions

**Change the database**

Now I simply wanted to change the database.

```
mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);

mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db1); // $dbn1
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db2); // $dbn2
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();"); // $dbn2 <- still the same
```

Selecting the database with given resource the last connection (obviously) does not change. This means that for function calls with omitted `$link` parameter the database still is wrong.

**Change the database (without `$link` paramter)**

```
mysql_select_db($dbn1); // no $link parameter

mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db1); // $dbn1
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db2); // $dbn1 <- now this is wrong
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();"); // $dbn1
```

Changing the database without `$link` parameter the database of `$db2` changes. Even though they are forced to a new resource object. (The resource objects are different, I checked them.) Connecting `$db2` to database `$dbn2` again (with given `$link`) will change the last connection (last query) again.

So changing the database does not change the `$link` resource which makes sense. So the `$link` variable stored internally in php for the `mysql_*` functions is wrong.

**Re-opening the connection**

```
$db1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);

mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db1); // $dbn1
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();", $db2); // $dbn1 <- now this is wrong again
mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE();"); // $dbn1
```

I tried to create a new connection without forcing a new `$link`. This way the last created connection is the connection I want. But now the `$db2` is wrong. This also makes sense because `$db1` and `$db2` are on the same server. Opening a new connection with the same data and not forcing a new connection will of course overwrite both of them (I did not check this).

**Super ugly and messy solution**

The only solution I came up with is to recreate the connection for `$db2` and then recreate the connection for `$db1` again. So I create the database connections again and again. The code (summarized and simplified, of course this is not in one file. Also I cannot simply remove the first lines!) looks like this:

```
// the $db1 and $db2 are created elsewhere so they will always exist
$db1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 
$db2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);
mysql_select_db($dbn2, $db2);

// in the actual database files before accessing the database
$db2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
mysql_select_db($dbn2, $db2);

$db1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 
mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);
```

But in my eyes this looks super ugly and redundant. The problem is that the database objects `$db1` and `$db1` are used very often also in asynchronous ajax requests. Sometimes there is just one of the database resources.

In addition the last 4 lines of the above code has to be done before every request of `$db1` or after every request of `$db2`. This seems like a huge mess for me.

**So my overall question is**: Does somebody have an idea how I can fix this?

*Note:* Replacing all function is not an option. Also I know that `mysql` is deprecated and removed in PHP 7 but again I cannot replace the functions. Also simply creating the `$db2` before the `$db1` is not possible. Both database connections are created on different code points or parallel, in ajax requests indipendently from eachother. It is simply not possible to guarantee the order of creating. In addition I need some data from `$db1` to use `$db2`.

**Edit**

> In addition the last 4 lines of the above code has to be done before every request of `$db1` or after every request of `$db2`.

To clarify this line: In the code there also is a `Database` class. There is one object `$database` for database 1 and connection `$db1` and one object for `$new_database` for database 2 and connection `$db2`.

At first there was only one database connection. This was the reason for previous programmers to simply wrote things like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `example_table` WHERE id = 100;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then the `Database` class was invended. The now written code is like:

```
$database->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `example_table` WHERE id = 100;");
$result = $database->getAssocResult();
```

Now we introduced another database. Now there are also lines with

```
$new_database->setQuery(...);
...
```

All those variants exist parallel in the code. In 10,000 different files in a huge amount of lines. Database 2 *is always and only used together with the `Database` class and the `$new_database` object*. With the quoted line I talk about modifying the `Database` class.

```
class Database{
    protected function query(){
        // handle the actual query stuff

        global $db1, $dbn1, $dbn2;
        if($this->database_name == $dbn2){
            $this->link = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password); 
            mysql_select_db($dbn2, $this->link);

            $db1 = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, true); 
            mysql_select_db($dbn1, $db1);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This way the database connection to `$db1` will always be reset to the old database. Now the `mysql_*` functions can be used. But this solution is very ugly as I said.

Comment: Your connection strings should be defined somewhere. Where they are defined (whether they are in a seperate connection file or in the same) is where you should change the value (in this case, the database name).

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you. I know that (read the last *Note* section). There also is written why this is no option for me.

Comment: @Sanguinary Sorry but I don't think I understand what you mean. I have two connections working parallel. What do you mean I should change?

Comment: I don’t think there is a proper solution for this, with the restrictions you are imposing. And your “ugly & messy” solution would still require that you make modifications in all the places where the actual queries are executed, am I getting that correctly? Then what’s the difference between doing _that_, and modifying the actual function calls in those places?

Comment: @misorude Hmm, I was expecting that. There is a difference but I did not include that in my question to simplify it. I use two database classes for `$db1` and `$db2`. But there is old code which uses the database 1 **without** the database class. The `$db2` is newer and **only used with the object**. So modifying the database class for `$db2` is easy. This will affect all queries done by `$db2`. For `$db1` this is not possible because of some direct code with the `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: _“In addition the last 4 lines of the above code has to be done before every request of $db1 or after every request of $db2.”_ - so that would mean modifying stuff _around_ all places where any of the old `mysql_` functions are called? Then modifying the function calls themselves would still make more sense IMHO. (Not saying switch out `mysql_query` for another function/method, but explicitly add the connection identifier to those calls.)

Comment: @misorude I updated my answer to explain what I mean with this line. I hope it's more clear now. Thank you for still trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead of mysql it will work...

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I already got this answer in the comments. Please read my full question. There is written three times that this is not a solution and why it is not a solution.